# How can I find my custom order attribute?

Tags: magento-1.7, database, attributes, sales-order

When I export my orders I have a custom attribute called "calc_fields" somehow saved inside "**product_options**" under "**info_buyRequest**"

The information is saving correctly in my event listener when a product is added to the cart. I have data that saves using

```
   $items[0]->setData("calc_fields", $calcFields);
```

This means that the calc_fields attribute was created at one point.  In my history I have no code related to creating an attribute for **calc_fields**. And when I check my database tables:

`sales_flat_order`

`sales_flat_order_item`

`sales_flat_quote_item_option`

When I go to any of these tables and click to view the Structure in cPanel the attribute "calc_fields" doesn't exist.

***How can I be referencing this attribute and saving data to it if it isn't in my database?***

Comment: Magento version?

Comment: updated question!